# kernel mode driver write to file

Tags: windows, kernel, driver

I am working on a windows keyboard filter driver and I need to write to a file. I tried using zwcreate,zwwrite, and zwclose but the driver is not running at PASSIVE_LEVEL and I got the BSOD. I have never written a windows driver before. Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Thanks J. Passing!

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a good idea to let the kernel driver write to a file in the first place. The best way to do that IMHO is to provide a user space program that communicates with the driver, gets the data and then writes it to disk.

Comment: Should we be helping him, he's almost certainly trying to write a keylogger.

Comment: I will admit I am writing a keylogger. :)

Comment: Why are you writing a keylogger?

Comment: @Blank I could't think of any other type of driver to write.

Comment: This is old as hell but i had a good laugh cuz in 2021 im writing a "keylogger" driver too. Except the filter is really only gonna log one particular key and write other info to a file. If Ana has to know trying to write a keylog filter for Windows is the only useful thing to do for me to actually learn how to code a Windows Driver and finally learn Windows internals. Good task. Also in 2021 their is DSE so keyloggers on that layer arent really even useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Schedule workitems (IoAllocateWorkItem/IoQueueWorkItem) and handle all file I/O from within the workitem callback routines.

> I'm not sure if it is a good idea to let the kernel driver write to a file in the first place. The best way to do that IMHO is to provide a user space program that communicates with the driver, gets the data and then writes it to disk.

This is true for Unix, but not for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

```
PCUCHAR buffer[] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03};    //  for example
ULONG bufferSize = sizeof(buffer);

UNICODE_STRING      filePath;   //  Must be with DOS prefix: \??\C:\MyFolder\logs.txt
HANDLE              hFile;
OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES   ObjectAttributes;
IO_STATUS_BLOCK     IoStatusBlock;

InitializeObjectAttributes(&ObjectAttributes, &filePath, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE | OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE, NULL, NULL);

NTSTATUS Status = ZwCreateFile(&hFile, FILE_GENERIC_READ | FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, &ObjectAttributes,
    &IoStatusBlock, NULL, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0, FILE_CREATE,
    FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT, NULL, 0);

if (!NT_SUCCESS(Status))
{
    DbgPrint("[DRV_NAME]: Creating file error");
    return Status;
}

Status = ZwWriteFile(hFile, NULL, NULL, NULL, &IoStatusBlock, (PVOID)buffer, bufferSize, NULL, NULL);

if (!NT_SUCCESS(Status))
{
    InjDbgPrint("[DRV_NAME]: Writing file error");
    return Status;
}

ZwClose(hFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

A wonderful example for using Zw-Tools to write files from a device driver is Clandestiny's Klog found at [rootkit.com](http://www.rootkit.com/board_project_fused.php?did=proj21). It is currently helping me a lot.

And well, I kinda agree with Johannes that it is not advisable to do classical userland-work (file/net/...-access) directly from a driver. Not only is it errorprone, it is also might break unforseeable in the future. User interfaces normally are much more steady and resilient.

Comment: sadly the link does not work anymore...